# Loop through <td> elements and define rows / columns

Tags: c#, html, xpath, matrix, html-agility-pack

I have an HtmlNodeCollection of HTML `<td>` elements that I have collected from a table using HTMLAgilityPack. Normally, I would just select the `<tr>` elements in the table and loop through the `<td>` elements, but unfortunately the `<tr>` opening tag is generated through JavaScript and isn't rendered from the server. I have no control over how the HTML is rendered. Therefore, I've resorted to getting an HtmlNodeCollection from this XPATH query:

```
HtmlNode table = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@width='100%' and @cellpadding='1' and @cellspacing='1' and @border='0']");
HtmlNodeCollection tds = table.SelectNodes(".//td[@align and string-length(@width)=0]"); // only select td elements that have the align attribute and don't have a width attribute
```

In the table, there are six columns and any number of rows. I'd like to process each individual row and parse out the columns into an intermediate data structure. I have this code for getting each "row" and "column", but it isn't quite correct:

```
int cols = 6; // six columns
int rows = tds.Count / cols;

// loop through the rows
for (int row = 1; row <= rows; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
    {
        HtmlNode td = tds[col * row]; // get the associated td element from the column index * row index
        MessageBox.Show(td.InnerHtml + "\n" + td.InnerText);
    }
}
```

I start at row 1 instead of row 0 and end at the row count since I don't want to multiply zero out six times. I'm attempting to treat this as a matrix, but I'm having trouble defining when one row ends and the next one starts. Do you have any suggestions on how to properly loop through all rows and columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After drawing out a grid on paper, it became clear what I was missing. I needed to add the column index to the number of columns multiplied by the current row like this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
    {
        HtmlNode td = tds[col + cols * row]; // get the associated td element from the column index * row index
        MessageBox.Show(td.InnerHtml + "\n" + td.InnerText);
    }
}
```